# I burned my peace lily in the sun

Tags: leaves

Can i revive it leaves are wilted and black.  I had gnats pulled the plant out of the dirt to change it i still had a ball of soil on the roots placed the root in a plastic bag but left it in the sun tooo long . When I came back the leaves were burned black wilted.   It was a plant from my dad's funeral. What can i do to revive it?   I did place the roots in water for 3 days and just planted it in a small pot....

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have already potted up the rootball in new potting soil in a pot. Its probably best to cut off all the severely damaged leaves - other than that, there's nothing you can do other than position it somewhere with bright daylight but no sun, water when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, and don't leave the plant standing in water in any outer tray or pot. It'll either recover or it won't.

Comment: Yes I  did put it in a pot thanks for the help.